# .sh file cannot open file with "." command

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have this following shell script (test.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
. /home/detail/env3/bin/activate
```

But when I execute it via `sh test.sh`, it returns an error:

```
test.sh: 2: .: Can't open /home/detail/env3/bin/activate
```

All permissions are set to 777. Can anyone help — what's wrong?

Result of `ls -l /home/detail/env3/bin/activate`

[image]

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 detail detail 2076 Aug 14 10:49 /home/detail/env3/bin/activate
```

Comment: Permissions should not be set to 777; you don't want everyone to modify your files.  You haven't shown the result of `ls -l /home/detail/env3/bin/activate` — what do you see/ . (Note that to 'dot' a file, you only need read permission on the file.)

Comment: @Ronald : First, it is odd that you want to run a file which seems to be intended for bash, using sh. This might get you in trouble later, but is not the reason for the current error message. Can you `cat` the file? Did you check the file for correct line endings and hidden characters, in particular around line 2?

Comment: Does the file `test.sh` have CRLF (WIndows/DOS) line endings, or does it have Unix (Linux) line endings?  It could be that you're looking for a file name that ends with a carriage return, and not finding it because the filename doesn't end with a carriage return.

Comment: hint: for better readability replace `.` by `source`

Comment: Hint: for better compatibility, keep `.` and don't use `source`.  If you want a C shell, use the C shell.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming and should rather be asked on askubuntu.com or similar sites

Comment: It is about how to get a program (a shell script _is_ a program) to work.  It is on topic for SO.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler compatibility with what? `source` and the `.` are synonyms + he explicitely calls `/bin/bash`

Comment: Better compatibility with POSIX shells, and other shells that are not Bash.  Since the OP runs the code using `sh`, it could easily be `dash` or some other shell that's being used.  You'll also have to accept that I have an aversion to C shells, and the C shell notations that were imported into Bash.  Like I said, if you want a C shell, use the C shell.

Comment: What do you get if you run `sh test.sh 2>&1 >/dev/null | od -c`?  Is there a `\r` in the output?  What do you get if you run `file test.sh`?

Comment: where you see he runs using `sh`? also in most nowadays distros `sh` symlinks to something less ancient.

Comment: to whoever who down-voted this, programming god bless you! :P

Comment: DOS line endings will not prevent the shell from *opening* the file; they will just cause problems with parsing and evaluating the contents.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski  "But when I execute it via `sh test.sh` [...]". And `dash` (which is what ubuntu uses for `/bin/sh`) is not ancient; nobody is suggesting that `sh` is really the original Bourne shell.

Comment: `sh` in my question stands for `sh` shell.

Comment: [_"Where you see he runs using `sh`?"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59854242/sh-file-cannot-open-file-with-command#comment105843094_59854242)   I see it in the question at "But when I execute it via `sh test.sh`" — that looks like a use of `sh` rather than `bash` directly.

Answer (score 1):

On an (antique) RHEL 5 Linux box, I created a file `xyz.sh` with a CRLF line ending on the only line;

```
0x0000: 2E 20 70 71 72 2E 73 68 0D 0A                     . pqr.sh..
0x000A:
```

I created a file `pqr.sh` with regular Unix line endings:

```
echo $0 at work
```

I tried to run the first script with `sh`:

```
$  sh xyz.sh
: No such file or directory
$ bash xyz.sh
xyz.sh: line 1: .: $'pqr.sh\r': file not found
$
```

When I run that through a hex dump program, I get:

```
$ sh xyz.sh 2>&1 | xxd -g 1
0000000: 78 79 7a 2e 73 68 3a 20 6c 69 6e 65 20 31 3a 20  xyz.sh: line 1: 
0000010: 70 71 72 2e 73 68 0d 3a 20 4e 6f 20 73 75 63 68  pqr.sh.: No such
0000020: 20 66 69 6c 65 20 6f 72 20 64 69 72 65 63 74 6f   file or directo
0000030: 72 79 0a                                         ry.
$
```

When I eliminate the CR from `xyz.sh` and run it, I get:

```
$ sh xyz.sh
xyz.sh at work
$
```

Given this experimentation, I deduce that the problem in the question probably arises because the file `test.sh` has CRLF line endings, so when the shell processes it, it is trying to open a file `$'/home/detail/env3/bin/activate\r'` in the Bash notation.  The error message also suggests that the shell in `/bin/sh` is not actually Bash (or Bash has changed its error messages over time).  Running `sh --version` might or might not be informative.

You could prove the CRLF problem with:

```
$ file xyz.sh
xyz.sh: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
$
```

except you'd specify `test.sh`.  You can convert the file to Unix line endings using `vim` and `:set fileformat=unix` before writing the file back to disk:

```
$ file xyz.sh
xyz.sh: ASCII text
$
```

This testing says nothing about whether the file in `/home/detail` has CRLF (DOS-style) line endings; the shell isn't getting as far as reading that file yet.

FWIW: `dash` 0.5.9 running on a Mac (running macOS Mojave 10.14.6) produces yet another error message:

```
$ dash xyz.sh
: not found.: pqr.sh
$ dash xyz.sh 2>&1 | xxd -g 1
00000000: 78 79 7a 2e 73 68 3a 20 31 3a 20 2e 3a 20 70 71  xyz.sh: 1: .: pq
00000010: 72 2e 73 68 0d 3a 20 6e 6f 74 20 66 6f 75 6e 64  r.sh.: not found
00000020: 0a        
$
```

Similarly, `ksh` produces:

```
$ ksh xyz.sh
: cannot open [No such file or directory]
$ ksh xyz.sh 2>&1 | xxd -g 1
00000000: 78 79 7a 2e 73 68 5b 31 5d 3a 20 2e 3a 20 70 71  xyz.sh[1]: .: pq
00000010: 72 2e 73 68 0d 3a 20 63 61 6e 6e 6f 74 20 6f 70  r.sh.: cannot op
00000020: 65 6e 20 5b 4e 6f 20 73 75 63 68 20 66 69 6c 65  en [No such file
00000030: 20 6f 72 20 64 69 72 65 63 74 6f 72 79 5d 0a      or directory].
$
```

All this suggests that the shell in `/bin/sh` on the OP's machine is not Bash, Dash or Ksh.

Answer (score 0):

On my linux machine I've created two files in /tmp/test1 folder to simulate your situation:

```
// hello.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo 'hello'
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash
. /tmp/test1/hello.sh
```

I've done `chmod 755` on both files and run `test.sh`:

```
mark@whatever@/tmp/test1# ./test.sh
```

I do see that it outputs `hello` so the possible reason is:
Lack of permissions.  On one of folders `/home`, `/home/detail`, `/home/detail/env3` ...

Comment: it has no problems when using echo. and permissions is not a problem since I already have the sh file in 777 and the env3 folder as 777 too

Comment: @MarkBramnik : Could a lack of permissions of the folders in the path really a problem? If this were the case, the `ls -l` shouldn't have worked either.